# phpmyadmin is this Index Size?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Good day, newbie on php here.

I use phpmyadmin mqysql, my problem is i don't know what should i put in the encircle field shown in the picture below (also know what is this and how to use it) [image]

[image]

I proceeded not giving any value on it and it happens whenever i make a primary key or unique key on a table i created. Is this what they call index size? i tried searching this on internet and see other tutorials but i don't see any mentions on this(maybe im googling it wrong?).

- So what does this do?
- what value should i put here?
- what is the default value of this?
- when using unique, what do veterans put on index name when selecting unique?

i hope you could enlighten or teach it to me because its quite vague now that im self studying it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That with the index size is very simple. imagine that you create an index on a VARCHAR (16) column. In this case the index entry is created with 16 characters. Now it can be that the strings already differ in the first characters. In such a case, the length of the index can e.g. 8 set.

This makes the index shorter, uses less memory and is therefore faster. If there are several entries in the column that are the same in the first 8 characters, all these rows are found via the index and the comparison which row really fits is then made by comparing the individual rows. So if the number of entries found is very high, the whole thing will be slower.

check how many equal entries in the table with a shorter index

```
+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
| id | rev | content                                           |
+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
|  2 |   1 | One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin |
|  1 |   1 | The earth is flat                                 |
|  3 |   2 | The earth is flat and rests on a bull's horn      |
|  5 |   5 | The earth is flat type                            |
|  4 |   3 | X The earth is like a ball.                       |
+----+-----+---------------------------------------------------+

 SELECT d.*,count(*) as cnt
 FROM docs as d
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(d.content,1,8)
 ORDER BY cnt DESC;
    
 +----+-----+---------------------------------------------------+-----+
 | id | rev | content                                           | cnt |
 +----+-----+---------------------------------------------------+-----+
 |  1 |   1 | The earth is flat                                 |   3 |
 |  2 |   1 | One hundred angels can dance on the head of a pin |   1 |
 |  4 |   3 | X The earth is like a ball.                       |   1 |
 +----+-----+---------------------------------------------------+-----+
 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```